# When java program write the file using FileOutputStream, same time I paste the file, FileNotFoundException thrown

Tags: java, windows, copy-paste, filenotfoundexception

Let me explain the situation. In Windows OS.

- My java program writes the logfile.
- Usually It's OK, but when I copying and pasting the logfile(ctrl + c and v),
  java throws exception `java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\log.txt (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)`
- After I research the problem, I found this exception throws by pasting the file. Not copying.

**Please tell me why this exception occur.**

Reproduce code is below(encode "Windows-31J" is japanese, there is no 
 particular meaning). Excecute this program and copy and paste "C:\log.txt".

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class FileNotFound {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    IntStream.range(0, 100000).parallel().forEach(
      i -> {
        try {
          fileWrite("C:\\log.txt", String.valueOf(i));
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    );
  }

  public static void fileWrite(String filePath, String str) throws IOException {

    try (FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
        OutputStreamWriter ow = new OutputStreamWriter(fw, "Windows-31J");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(ow);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {

      out.println(str);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IOException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because another process, i.e. your Explorer window, is using the file, via the 'copy' action, which Windows does not allow. Solution: don't.

Comment: Thank you, It is no wonder. But windows shortcut key past(ctrl + v) get exclusive lock?

Comment: I don't see why it would be anything other than the copy step (Ctrl/c).